# New tiles not being added in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-8.1, windows-8-apps

So I updated to Windows 8.1 tonight and I noticed after installing a few new apps, that their associated tiles where not being automatically added to the Metro interface, however they can be manually added.

Is this the expected new behavior of Windows 8.1 or is there something going on with my computer?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior in Windows 8.1 and for me the most important change. I always hated that the start screen is floated with a lot of crap in Windows 8 that I always have to unpin.